# Anaconda Virtual Env Python script not executing

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to use a virtual environment in anaconda on Ubuntu. I start my environment using `source activate testEnv` just fine.

However, if I run the command `python`, I get the following error:

`bash: /home/user/anaconda/envs/testEnv/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

If I am not in the virtual environment, and I cd to `/home/user/anaconda/envs/testEnv/bin/`, I can run `python` perfectly fine.

However, from any other location, say my home directory, I try to run `/home/user/anaconda/envs/testEnv/bin/python`, I get the same error as above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on https://askubuntu.com/ another site on the stack exchange network.

Comment: try reinstalling anaconda there's probably a setting up issue, also what about when you specify python3 ? or python2 depending on what you used to setup your environment

Comment: The new command is `conda activate <env-name>`, not `source activate ...`. Please try the new command and see if it is fixed